# Multidimensional array and memory usage

Tags: memory-management, multidimensional-array

I am working on building a class that holds a collection of objects in a grid that can be either 2D or 3D.  I am using multidimensional arrays as the collection of objects will not change size once initialized.  Currently, I am declaring the 2D arrays as: `myArray[x][y][1]`.  This allows the same functions to work independent of the actual dimensions of my collection.  Is there a major difference in the amount of memory allocated this way over `myArray[x][y]`?  I am working on this in Java but I have been considering switching over to C++ once I get the logic working the way I want.

Comment: of course, for count the memory you can multiply each dimension, in example you have 3 dimensional array x, y, z total memory used is x*y*z * (data type size)

Comment: Thanks.  I was fairly certain that the memory allocated for the objects themselves wouldn't change but by adding that third dimension to the array, even if the length is 1, am I not adding x * y pointers since the second dimension will be assigned as arrays with a length of 1 instead of just as an object location?

Comment: x[2][1], you have x[0][0], x[1][0]. actually you allocate x, x[0], x[1] reference/pointer for holding the second dimension. you can find out size of this pointer/reference